# Stop android service after crashing the app

Tags: android, android-service

I have 3 activities in my app and I have a service which is running in my App from activity 1 then I go to activity 2 and then activity 3. Suppose the app crashes at activity 3, The UI returns to activity 2 but the service keeps on executing in the background. I want to stop the service whenever any activity crashes. Will unbinding the service in Thread.uncaughtexceptionhandler help or should I need to do something else?

Comment: are you returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`? Try with `START_NOT_STICKY`

Comment: I tried with START_NOT_STICKY also but no helps. And I also tried to unbind my all services inside the Thread.uncaughtexceptionhandler but it was also not working @LordRaydenMK

Comment: if your service is started in a separated process (how you add service in manifest/ `process` attribute) then i think it will not be killed by a crash, only if it's work is done, or if OS for some reason decided to kill it (resources issues). OR if you cann `stopService()` somehow ...

Comment: I didn't specify this attribute in the manifest so whatever is the default it is getting that process.

Comment: If your `Activity` crashes, this crashes the entire OS process, which includes your `Service`. Android is nice enough to restart a crashed `Service` automatically. Why don't you make your code robust so that it doesn't crash.

Comment: I was preparing for the worst case scenario :p